# Using Zurb Foundation 6 javascript with jspm

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I have an es6 module defined like this:

```
import 'zurb/foundation/js/foundation.core';
import 'zurb/foundation/js/foundation.util.mediaQuery';
import 'zurb/foundation/js/foundation.dropdown';
import 'zurb/foundation/js/foundation.reveal';
import 'zurb/foundation/js/foundation.tabs';
import modalFactory from './modal';
import revealCloseFactory from './reveal-close';

export default function ($element) {
    debugger;
    $element.foundation();
}
```

As you can see, there is a breakpoint towards the top of the default export function.

I then use this module in a file like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import foundation from './global/foundation';

export default class Global extends PageManager {
    loaded(next) {
        foundation($(document));
        next();
    }
}
```

When this runs, I get an error that `$element.foundation` is not a function. Using the `debugger` statement, I can inspect the current scope when the execution pauses. I'm able to confirm that `$element` does not have a `foundation()` method. I'm not sure why this is the case since foundation has been imported at the top of the file.

Also, when the execution pauses, on the js console, if I do `$(document).foundation()`, it works, and foundation is in fact a function. Also, `$element.is($(document))` returns `true`.

Why would the `foundation` method be available on `$(document)` and not `$element`?

Additionally, if I change the line to from `foundation($(document))`, to `foundation(jQuery(document))`, it works. I can also see that if I put a breakpoint right before that line, `$.fn.foundation` does not exist, but `jQuery.fn.foundation` does.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is most likely the fact that the code that generates the jQuery object doesn't import foundation, hence when the object is created, the `foundation` function isn't part of the prototype.

Add the foundation import to the code that creates the object.

Comment: This makes sense, but I am having trouble seeing if it applies to my situation. The jQuery object is generated in the second code snippet, which imports `jquery`, and then `foundation` at the top of the file. So doesn't that mean the `foundation` function should be available?

Comment: Please check my additional info on the question. It looks like `jQuery` has the `foundation` method, but `$` doesn't.